# Can I execute several WHERE LIMIT statements in one query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I came across something like this:

```
      country    | year | total
  ---------------+------+-------
   Romania       | 2004 |    20
   United States | 2004 |    19
   Japan         | 2004 |     9
   Russia        | 2004 |     8
   China         | 2004 |     3
   Latvia        | 2004 |     1
   Canada        | 2004 |     1
   Ukraine       | 2004 |     1
   China         | 2008 |    24
   United States | 2008 |    20
   Japan         | 2008 |     7
   Romania       | 2008 |     7
   Uzbekistan    | 2008 |     1
   Spain         | 2008 |     1
   South Korea   | 2008 |     1
   North Korea   | 2008 |     1
   Russia        | 2012 |    12
   China         | 2012 |    12
   United States | 2012 |    10
   Great Britain | 2012 |     8
   South Korea   | 2012 |     1
   Ukraine       | 2012 |     1
```

My problem is I'm trying to execute a single query that will give me 3 rows from each year ordered by the total column.

Result would look like:

```
      country    | year | total
  ---------------+------+-------
   Romania       | 2004 |    20
   United States | 2004 |    19
   Japan         | 2004 |     9
   China         | 2008 |    24
   United States | 2008 |    20
   Japan         | 2008 |     7
   Russia        | 2012 |    12
   China         | 2012 |    12
   United States | 2012 |    10
```

I could get the data I wanted if I executed 3 separate queries, each having a LIMIT of 3 and using

```
WHERE year = 2004, WHERE year = 2008, and WHERE year  = 2012
```

But I can't figure out if this is possible using one query? Some insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the window function [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY total DESC) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
WHERE rn < 4
```

Comment: @juergend: Sure does. Postgres 8.4 or later ([released July 2009](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)). Follow my link to the manual ...

Answer (score 1):

Well if this was t-sql i'd make use of row number and partition it by the year.

```
select country, year, total from (
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by year order by total desc)
    from tbl
) where rn < 4
```